# Need to use BuiltInMic after connecting headphones also for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, avaudiosession

I am making an app in which i always want to take input from the device (iOS) BuiltInMic even if the headphones are plugged in. I have done a lot of research on it and came out with some solutions but they are not working.

I need to use this method to get the preferred input from a device :-

```
setPreferredInput:error:
```

More description can be found on this link :-

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1799/_index.html
```

I got stuck in the method parameters to be passed

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setPreferredInput:(AVAudioSessionPortDescription *)inPort error:&myAudioError];
```

i.e the inPort to be pass. I need to set it to AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic but i am not able to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From Api Documents

```
 - (BOOL)overrideOutputAudioPort:(AVAudioSessionPortOverride)portOverride
                      error:(NSError **)outError
```

`Calling this method with the AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker option and the audio session’s category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord causes audio to use the built-in speaker and microphone regardless of other settings. This change remains in effect only until the current route changes or you call this method again with the AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone option.`

Comment: @ Dinesh :- kindly check what i asked for... i need to use input for BuiltInMic. thanks for your help but its not the answer i need.